# Compilation issues in OpenGL code with g++

Tags: c++, opengl, g++

When I try compiling the opengl Code written in c language with gcc with the following commands it runs fine :

```
gcc -Wall tutorial10.c -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

But when I try doing the same compiling it by using g++

```
g++ -Wall tutorial10.c -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

It starts to give a lot of errors like this :

```
tutorial10.c: In function ‘void drawRect()’:
tutorial10.c:28:34: error: ‘glClearBufferfv’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:34:28: error: ‘glUseProgram’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:36:24: error: ‘glGenBuffers’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:37:37: error: ‘glBindBuffer’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:47:71: error: ‘glBufferData’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:49:52: error: ‘glVertexAttribPointer’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:50:29: error: ‘glEnableVertexAttribArray’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:52:60: error: ‘glGetUniformLocation’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:54:42: error: ‘glUniform4f’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:59:30: error: ‘glDisableVertexAttribArray’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
tutorial10.c:93:34: error: ‘glCreateProgram’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:95:54: error: ‘glCreateShader’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:124:76: error: ‘glShaderSource’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:128:36: error: ‘glCompileShader’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:134:49: error: ‘glAttachShader’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:136:29: error: ‘glLinkProgram’ was not declared in this scope
tutorial10.c:147:35: error: ‘glDeleteShader’ was not declared in this scope
```

---

Headers from comment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
```

Comment: it means that you didn't include the proper header

Comment: Just for your information, GCC checks the file extension to know what language you are compiling. A file ending in `.c` will always be compiled as C code. It doesn't matter if you use `g++` or not.

Comment: If this is a problem of header why is gcc able to compile it properly and run it ?

Comment: It looks as if the fixed function pipeline compiles and works fine with g++ but not the programmable pipeline which gives the error as above.

Comment: How do your includes look?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

Comment: What version of the OpenGL development libraries do you have installed? From which supplier?

Comment: OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.67

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have opengl functions declarations within your translation unit (most likely, you haven't included `<GL/gl.h>`).

`gcc` takes that because older versions of C language allows implicit declarations - whenever you use function, gcc automatically declares it with generic rules. It does **NOT** mean functions will be called properly - implicit rules are very generic and will cause problems on e.g. `float` argument types, so expect a lot of bugs here.

You can see warnings about implicit declarations if you add `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` (or `-Wall`, which includes this, along with many others) to your cflags.

`g++`, on other side, enabled C++ mode, which forbids implicit declarations.

To sum it all, don't use implicit declarations unless you truly understand what they do (but in that case you wouldn't want to use them anyway).

Comment: Its not working. Adding the header doesn't make any change. The conflict which I think is related to the programmable pipeline methods which I have used in the code. The fixed function pipeline compiles fine with g++.

Comment: Because `gl.h` have declarations for only GL 1.2. For newer versions, you should get extension function pointers at runtime using e.g. GLEW (or manually), or link to them directly at your own risk. If you want to go later path - look for e.g. `glext.h` or `gl2.h`.

Comment: Ok, I will try figure out the proper headers for g++. Thank You for the help .

Comment: Once again, it is not g++'s problem. If you'll call `glUniform4f` in your gcc version, it will compile, but function arguments will be all messed up, because implicit rules says it takes doubles and not floats. But anyway, if your needs isn't too unique just use GLEW, it is great. Only thing you need to add is `glewInit()` after context creation, and `#include <GL/glew.h>`

Comment: @user3640759 [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net) would be your easiest solution. It takes care of all GL function declarations there possibly are.

Comment: Thank you very much @keltar. The include of glew.h and  glewInit() method made the program work.